# how to fix this Error:Module 'packageName' production: java.lang.ClassCastExcept

Tags: java

Error:Module 'luggageWarehouseManagement' production: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$PrimitiveType cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType

Comment: https://www.codenong.com/cs107120251/

Comment: I found it! must Rebuild Project and then Reload All from Disk

Comment: Thank you any way!